# Laravel override renderer view

Tags: php, laravel, view, overriding, renderer

I would like that as soon as an ajax request is sent where there is view ('view') instead of returning the raw view its returns a JSON

Like that:

```
/**
     * @param \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View $view
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function ajaxResponse (View $view)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'id' => $view->getData()['page'],
            'title' => $view->getData()['title'],
            'content' => $view->renderSections()['content'],
            'replacepage' => null,
        ]);
    }
```

But I absolutely don't know how to do it I don't want to repeat myself in each controller

I have tried to replace View with mine but it does not work as I would like everything to work but I cannot recover the section of my page

```
<?php

namespace App\Extensions\View;

use Illuminate\View\View;

class AjaxView extends View
{
    /**
     * Get the contents of the view instance.
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    protected function renderContents()
    {
        if(request()->ajax()) {
            echo $this->getResponse($this->getData());
            exit;
        }

        return parent::renderContents();
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return false|string
     */
    public function getResponse (array $data = [])
    {
        return json_encode([
            'id' => $data['page'],
            'title' => (!empty($data['title']) ? $data['title'] . ' - ' . config('app.name') : null),
            'content' => $this->renderSections()['content'],
            'replacepage' => null
        ]);
    }

}
```

This returns:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can do it this way:
In `app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php`, add method `response()`;

```
protected function view($viewPath, $content, $status = 200, array $headers = [])
{
        if(request()->ajax()) {
            return response()->json($content, $status, $headers);
        }

        return view($viewPath, $content);
}
```

Your controller methods can then use like this:

```
public function create()
{
  // logic
  return $this->view('view_path', $data);
}
```

Comment: I can't get view data is undefined inside request()->ajax() my $view->getData() is empty array but outside request()->ajax() is my $view->getData() is not empty

Comment: If you followed my example correctly, view data should be available as $content inside the view() method defined in your base controller.

Comment: i fixed it thans you

Answer (score 0):

I have change your function by

```
protected function ajaxView(string $viewPath, array $content = [], int $status = 200, array $headers = [])
    {
        $view = view($viewPath, $content);

        if(request()->ajax()) {
            dd($view->getData());
            return response()->json([
                'id' => $this->view->getData()['page'],
                'title' => $this->view->getData()['title'],
                'content' => $this->view->renderSections()['content'],
                'replacepage' => null,
            ], $status, $headers);
        }

        return $view;
    }
```

But the dd() record array is empty if i put my dd() outside of my if the record is not empty